# Adding an ImageUrl to an ImageControl

Tags: asp.net, image, webforms, imageurl

I need help how to add an `ImageUrl` to an `ImageControl` programmatically. I got this code, but I can't (I don't know how) add path that is stored in database.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string str = FileUpload1.FileName;
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".") + "//images//" + str);
        string path = "~//images//" + str.ToString();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into upload  values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + path + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Label1.Text = "Image uploaded";           
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select img from upload", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        Image1.ImageUrl = 
    }
    else 
    {
        Label1.Text = "Please select image"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I (somewhat) improved your code formatting, but your code sample is still incomplete, you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that particular scenario, you already have an image filename and path. All you need is `Image1.ImageUrl =  ResolveUrl("~/images/" + fileName);`.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
        string path = string.Format("{0}\\images\\{1}", 
           HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, fileName);
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);

        /* Save image information to database */            

        Image1.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("~/images/" + fileName);
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Please select image";
    }
}
```

***FYI:*** Your code is prone to SQL Injection attack. Make sure you use Parameterized Query.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to get path from database. I don't used Parameterized query because this is just example.

Comment: Ideally, you should not store the entire path of an image in database. The reason is folder structure might change time to time. So, you ***just store file name in database***, and append the file name to path dynamically like `Image1.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("~/images/" + fileName);`